# Java GUI и кириллица

Tags: gui, кодировка, java

В общем, хочу русифицировать jEdit (блокнот, написанный на джаве) для своего проекта, но есть проблема с кириллицей, я попытался заменить название окна "About" на "О программе", вместо желаемого результата я получил кракозябры, все файлы проекта в utf8, пробовал запускать

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -jar jedit.jar  
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar jedit.jar
```

Толку 0. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти наверняка нужная вам строка находится в одном из .properties файлов и соответственно загружается в java.util.Properties класс, который, в свою очередь, не чувствителен к кодировке (обрабатывает содержимое файла исключительно по одному байту, что равносильно использованию ISO8859-1). Это значит, что как бы Вы не меняли кодировку файла и какие бы директивы не указывали, ничего из этого не выйдет.

**Но:** к счастью, Properties поддерживает unicode escape-последовательности (\uxxxx), так что все, что нужно сделать - это закодировать все "нечитабельные" символы вот таким вот способом. Думаю, найти какую-нибудь масенькую утилитку для перегона туда/обратно не составит труда, можно даже и самому написать.

Comment: Подходящая утилита называется native2ascii и входит в состав JDK.